# How to retype the password or skip if the password is wrong

Tags: selenium

Dears

My question is about  using  python selenium  for automatic logging to multiple sites, one of the site I put a wrong password, and it return "Invalid username or password" and my code stopped on that site, how to re-type (try) a different password  or skip this site  in case it failed for the 2nd time?

Still struggling but no luck, below is my code

```py
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr[9]/td/form/input[6]")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("username")
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr[9]/td/form/input[7]")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr[9]/td/form/input[8]").click()

and I am expect this error if my password is wrong  "<td valign="top" align="left" class="err_msg_red">*Incorrect username or password. Please try again.</td>"
xpath for it:
"//*[@id=\"main-view\"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/ng-view/div/form/div[6]/div")) eql true
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to handle post login scenario , like  what happens when successfull login ..and what will happen if login unsuccessful .

so if login unsuccessful then :

use

```
try{

//your code here for login 
//Enter username
//Enter password
//Click login
//Verify url to check login successful , if not successful it will throw exception and catch that exception in the catch block 

}catch(Exception  e){

//If login unsuccessful then execute this block 
//Enter username 
//Enter password 

etc..

}
```

Comment: Hi,  still no luck, I have edit my question and put my code, or do you have an example I can follow it?